# Не заботает кнопка Android и Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager в IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk, sdk, avd

уже несколько часов мучаюсь с IntelliJ IDEA, пытаясь воткнуть в нее SDK.
про Android Studio знаю. но тк я сейчас хотел пройти урок, то нужно бы оставить IntelliJ IDEA...
архив с офф сайта с SDK tools package скачал, но как я понимаю последняя версия IntelliJ IDEA не собирается ничего запускать, а качает все сама, по крайней мере вариантом я найти не мог. поэтому он не особо пригодился... было предложено программой только папку создать, куда всю она сама загрузить в потом в сеттингс догрузить остальное...

Но в офф архиве я AVD manager вижу, может можно файлы в ручную воткнуть в папку программы , раз она распаковывать их себе не хожут, как и принимать распакованные помогите плз

в настройках  панели по идее кнопка должна быть, но ее нет,
SDK поставил, по обновлял, менеджера все равно нет

Помогите плз мудрым советом
гуглю четвертый час, честно
признаю что хреново...

Винда 10, IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Он не в Tools устанавливается, а в вариантах запуска проекта появляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]